# Equilibrium point from Differential equation does not match the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $$y'=-2+t-y$$.

I solved this linear differential equation and got $y=t-3$ as the solution.

And when I tried to solve this without having to solve the actual equation. I got the equilibrium point to be $y=t-2$ which does not match my solution. Why is this? Does this mean y=t-2 is not a solution.

When I plotted the direction field I found that y=t-2 is not in the solution. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equilibrium point because the differential equation is not autonomous: the right side has a $t$ in it.

$y = t-2$ is not a solution, as you can easily check by plugging this in to the differential equation.  What it is is a null isocline: a curve on which solutions have derivative $0$.

And, btw, $y = t-3$ is **a** solution, but it is not the general solution.
The general solution is $y = t-3+c e^{-t}$.

Comment: Also: the substitution $y=t+u$ gives an autonomous differential equation in $u$ with $u=-3$ as an equilibrium point, corresponding to the solution $y=t-3$.

Comment: So this means there is no equilibrium solutions for non autonomous differential equations? and you are right...i forgot to add the constant of integration while integrating..!!!!